# Can I find a list of devices that have downloaded my app from the apple store

Tags: ios, app-store

I posted the app on the apple store,I have a developer account and now I'm wondering if I can somehow find a list of all the devices that have downloaded my app?

Comment: No you can't. You could add an analytics framework to your app to get some more information

Comment: You think of something like Firebase Crashlytics? @Paulw11

Comment: Firebase analytics. Crashlytics is for crash reporting. There is also Microsoft app center and others

Answer (score 2):

On Apple's App Store Connect web site for your account :

- select App Analytics
- select your app
- select the Metrics tab in the upper left
- from the View By popup selector, select Device

and you will get chart of on which device types your app is being
   used, but only from that percentage of users who have opted in to sending Apple analytics.